# Cam phaser on 2008 Impala 3.5

Tags: engine, camshaft, rebuild

I'm getting ready to rebuild this motor and don't have experience with cam phasers. When taking the cam phaser off and reattach after rebuild, do I need to do anything specific to make sure there are no issues?

Comment: Basic or general instruction is to have the engine at TDC and refit the CPS, but you need to check the specific instructions for your engine.

Answer (score 1):

This style actuator is fairly simple. Clean it up a bit, inspect the return spring for damage, and inspect the valve for damage/pitting. Replace if needed. There is a filter in one of the holes behind the actuator, on the face of the cam, that needs to be replaced.